# Python in a webapp (client side)

Tags: python, apache-flex, html

This is part of some preliminary research and I am having a difficult time figuring out what options might be available or if this is even a situation where a solution even exists.

Essentially we have an existing python based simulation that we would like to make available to people via the web.  It can be pretty processor intensive, so while we could just run the sim server side and write a client that connects to it, this would not be ideal.

Writing a UI in Flash/Flex or HTML5, not a problem.  However, is there any way to keep the core simulation logic in python without having it live server side?  Is there any existing way to embed python modules in either of these technologies?

Thanks all.

Comment: Short answer: no, i don't think so.... wouldn't that mean that everyone needs to install python?

Comment: Technically yes, it can be done. In fact, providing a running Python interpreter inside a browser is one of the demos of [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), a LLVM-to-JavaScript compiler. However, this is more a technology demo than something usable.

Comment: @kindall I'm not sure thats exactly what they are asking for `" existing way"` ... they'd have to run python inside the browser to run the python code. But it still looks interesting.... can it run itself?

Answer (score 1):

Pyjamas: Python->Javascript, set of widgets for use in a browser or a desktop

Skulpt: Python written in Javascript

Emscripten: C/C++ -> LLVM -> Javascript

Empythoned: Based on emscripten and cpython, working on a stdlib?  There are bugs to file

Comment: Hrm.  Some interesting suggestions, thanks everyone.  A python interpreter running in the browser would probably be about the right idea.